# Tell me again why we need both .NET and Windows? Why can't Windows morph into the CLR?

Tags: clr

The same way DOS morphed into Windows?

We seem to have ended up supporting and developing for three platforms from Microsoft, and I'm not sure where the boundaries are supposed to lie.

Why can't the benefits of the CLR (such as type safety, memory protection, etc.) be built into Windows itself?

Or into the browser? Why an entirely other virtual machine? (How may levels of virtual machine indirection are we dealing with now? We just added Silverlight - and before that Flash - running inside the Browser running inside maybe a VM install...)

I can see raw Windows for servers, but why couldn't there be a CLR for workstations talking directly to the hardware (or at least not the whole Windows legacy ball and chain)?

(ooppp - I've got two questions here. Let's make this - why can't .net be built into Windows? I understand about backward compatibility - but the safety of what's in .NET could be at least optionally in Windows itself, couldn't it? It would just be yet another of many sets of APIs?)

Factoid - I recall that one of the competitor architectures selling against MS-DOS on the IBM PC was UCSD-pascal runtime - a VM.

Comment: Looks like Win8 (via WinRT) is beginning this process.

Comment: Or at least preinstall all versions of the CLR. (Yes, my .net 2.0 app needs to have .net 2.0 CLR installed on Win8 even though Win 8 has .net 4.0 which most people *say* is backward compatible (if you aren't making references to specific 2.0 stuff that changed in 4.0)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

And let's not forget that DOS didn't morph into Windows, at least not the Windows we know and love today. DOS was the operating system, Windows 3.1 a GUI shell resting atop said operating system.

When Windows 95 came out, it is true that there was no more boxed product labeled "Microsoft DOS," but Windows 95, architecturally, was DOS 7.0 with a GUI shell resting atop.

This continued through Win98 and WinME (aka Win9X).

The Windows we know today (XP, Vista, 2003, 2008) has its core from the Windows NT project, a totally separate beast. (Although NT was designed to be compatible with 3.1, and later, 9x binaries, and used a near-identical but expanded API.)

DOS no more morphed into the Windows we are familiar with than the original Linux core morphed into KDE.

The two APIs will need to continue to coexist as long as there are products built natively against Windows which are still in a support cycle. Considering that the Windows API still exists in Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7, that means at least 2017. Truthfully, it will probably be longer, because while managed code is a wonderful thing, it is not always the most appropriate/best answer.

Plus ... As a programmer, you ought to know better than anyone: It's never as easy to do something as it might appear from the outside!

Comment: Well, I guess it depends on the technical definition of "morph," right? :)

Comment: So I'm talking about doing exactly like from DOS to Windows. Support the old stuff until you can ditch those APIs; but offer a more tightly integrated CLR at the same time, and designate it as the obvious destination. It's stability should be at least equally featured as a core API.

Comment: So yes, in my view DOS did morph into Windows (supporing both kinds of apps long enough to make sure there was no exit strategy forced on their customers).

Comment: What are the characteristics of an app that shouldn't be newly developed in managed code? I'm conceding that you can't push redevelopment on everyone; and Win32 code written in C++ won't port easily to C++ - I know from personal experience. The stdlibs aren't on offer for managed code.

Comment: An app that has to run on a Pocket PC and a desk.. Both use mfc but it depends on the Hand held your targeting. 
An app that has to be small. I've got a few apps that sit on half a floppy. That includes all the dlls and extras. 
Apps where memory management is critical. (sometimes I want to delete)

Comment: Commercial, retail, boxed software. The ease of ILDASM and Reflector make trying to protect that kind of IP nigh-impossible. Definitely not appropriate for CLR in many (not all) scenarios. High-performance video, audio, imaging software where memory management is critical. There are others ...

Comment: As for as the first two comments from OP in this thread ... Microsoft already wants CLR to be your obvious destination in MOST scenarios. (They've even go so far as to begin recommending it for GAMES!) But it's still not for EVERY scenario, and hence there can be no Win32 exit strategy ... yet.

Comment: Actually, Windows 95 was a hypervisor with DOS and Windows running side-by-side in two separate VMs. See [Raymond Chen's article on that](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/24/6849530.aspx).

Comment: @Joey - Something not mentioned in that article: this was also true of Windows 3.1! The major difference is they hadn't written the 32-bit drivers for file system and networking at that stage (but they had by Wfw 3.11, which proudly said on the box that it included "Chicago" technology...)

Answer (score 9):

Windows is multi-million lines of code, most of it in C. This represents an enormous decades-long investment. It is constantly being maintained (fixed) for today's users. It would be completely impossible to stop the world while they rewrite every line in C# for ten years, then debug and optimise for another ten, without totally wrecking their business.

Some of the existing code could in theory be compiled to run on the CLR, but it would gain no benefit from doing so. Compiling a large subset of C to the CLR is possible (using the C++/CLI compiler) but it does not automatically enable garbage collection, for example. You have to redesign from the ground up to get that.

Comment: the .NET runtime is not written in C#. The OP is not asking to rewrite Windows on top of the CLR but have the CLR be an integral part of the OS. The benefits of doing that should be obvious as for example a garbage collector that runs at OS kernel level (underneath the virtual memory barrier) would be able to optimize memory usage far better that one written on top of the OS.

Answer (score 8):

Well, for one the CLR isn't an operating system. That's a pretty big reason why not ... I mean even the research OS, Singularity, is not just the CLR. I think you should read up on some books about the Windows kernel and general operating system stuff.

Comment: Of course it's not the OS. But it's a 100% abstraction above the OS that's sufficient to develop without dropping through and hurting yourself, and everyone else. What resources do you need from the OS that can't be provided through the CLR?

Comment: I can see some pretty strong arguments for integration between the OS and the CLR.  For example, if large-object-heap objects were rounded to 4K blocks, an OS could relocate them by manipulating the page maps without having to actually copy big blocks of memory.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft are still a few Windows releases away from that.
But they would start with something like [Singularity](http://research.microsoft.com/os/Singularity/) I think.

Comment: "without the overhead of hardware-protected isolation domains"
This means the kernel runs a VM, and all 'safe' apps can easily pass data back-n-forth with no I/O.  i.e. A code editor 'app' passes pointer to code buffer to the compiler app, which freezes the buffer (copy-on-write) and quickly creates a AST.  The buffer unfreezes, compiler/linker starts running multiple compilation/optimization/testing passes over the AST.  And this can all happen without file I/O, the CLR a.k.a. 'kernel VM' verifies integrity using only memory access.  Also very good for server-side big data (Hadoop) scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

because it would break backwards compatibility?  and mainstream chips architecture doesn't line up with VM architecture?  They [made hardware](http://www.ebb.org/bkuhn/writings/technical/thesis/node10.html) for a Java VM a while ago, but nobody cared.

Comment: "Morph" means you look like both for a while. Obviously it has to support existing apps.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest issue I see is that the CLR runs on a VM, and the VM is useful as a layer of abstraction. Some .NET apps can be run on Linux (see the Mono project, I think they are up to .NET 2 compatibility now), so that would all be gone.  In C/C++ or languages that directly talk to the hardware, you have to recompile your code into different binaries for every OS and hardware architecture. The point of having the VM there is to abstract that, so that you can write the code, build it, and use the exact same binary anywhere.  If you look at it from a Java perspective, they have done a much better job of using their VM as a "write once run anywhere" model. The same java classes will run on Windows, Mac, and Linux without rebuild (by the programmer anyway, technically the VM is doing that work).

I think the #1 point here is that .NET/CLR is NOT Windows specific, and IMO Microsoft would only help the .NET suite of languages if it put a little more effort toward cross-OS compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Because Microsoft has got a huge legacy they cannot just simply drop. Companies has invested lots of money for the Windows and Win32 software they cannot dismiss.

Answer (score 1):

CLR or some VM maybe used (VM's are being used) to run an OS on top of it . But then the question is, what should one use to build the VM? Probably C/C++ or some other similar language and (most) probably Assembly in some cases to speed up things.

That would mean the VM will still have the problems that Windows (or any OS) faces now. As pointed out by others, some part of the OS and related applications may be ported (or as you said morphed) to be over the VM, but getting the entire OS on top of a VM dosen't serve much purpose. The reason being, the VM will be the real OS then, implementing garbage collection and other protective measures for the Morphed OS.

Those are my two cents. :)

Answer (score 0):

What language would the CLR itself use? What APIs would it call? Say it needed to open a file or allocate memory or create a process, you think the CLR is going to do that? The CLR is built on top of native code. A managed OS would create overhead.

CLR is for app development, it is there to make it easy to make apps, and easy to make less buggy software. It uses a garbage collector, and they can destroy performance. They can be great too, but you usually end up with some kind of performance problems during development, caused by garbage collection.

They must make it backward compatible so they must make it have some kind of native API.

If you're saying let's make a pure 100% managed OS and forget backward compatibility or have some giant compatability later, all you're really saying is let's force a garbage collector onto everything, right? Besides a garbage collector and the portability guarantees you get by being CLI compliant, what are you getting? The algorithms and everything are still being compiled into native code by the time they execute, so the only really significant difference is the memory management.

Answer (score 0):

I actually did see trends that CLR will get planted deeper into the software stack.  I remember saw the newest windows software stack, some CLR related library get planted into lower levels.

But CLR won't morph into windows, we know backward compatibility is very important for the software ecology.